# Row-wise average of selected columns not working for my dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Yes, I've seen many other questions asked about how to compute a row-wise average, and have reproduced those methods with a trivial-sized dataframe. But none of these methods are working on my large dataset. Instead, .mean(axis=1) is returning only the value of the left-most column.

```
In [72]: pd.__version__
Out[72]: '1.0.3'

In [73]: df
Out[73]: 
       Constituent  Julian_day   Depth  ...  Seg_31  Elevation.5  mean
0      Temperature     37622.5  -0.585  ...    7.32          NaN  7.40
1      Temperature     37622.5  -1.670  ...    7.32          NaN  7.40
2      Temperature     37622.5  -2.670  ...    7.32          NaN  7.40
3      Temperature     37622.5  -3.670  ...    7.32          NaN  7.40
4      Temperature     37622.5  -4.670  ...    7.32          NaN  7.40
...            ...         ...     ...  ...     ...          ...   ...
87195          pH_     37986.5 -87.613  ...     NaN          NaN  6.77
87196          pH_     37986.5 -90.613  ...     NaN          NaN  6.77
87197          pH_     37986.5 -93.613  ...     NaN          NaN  6.75
87198          pH_     37986.5 -96.613  ...     NaN          NaN  6.73
87199          pH_     37986.5 -99.613  ...     NaN          NaN  6.71

[87200 rows x 15 columns]

In [74]: df[segs]
Out[74]: 
       Seg_11 Seg_24 Seg_25 Seg_26 Seg_31
0        7.40   7.49   7.48   7.48   7.32
1        7.40   7.49   7.48   7.48   7.32
2        7.40   7.49   7.48   7.48   7.32
3        7.40   7.49   7.48   7.48   7.32
4        7.40   7.49   7.48   7.48   7.32
...       ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
87195    6.77    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
87196    6.77    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
87197    6.75    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
87198    6.73    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
87199    6.71    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN

[87200 rows x 5 columns]

In [75]: df[segs].mean(axis=1)
Out[75]: 
0        7.40
1        7.40
2        7.40
3        7.40
4        7.40
         ... 
87195    6.77
87196    6.77
87197    6.75
87198    6.73
87199    6.71
Length: 87200, dtype: float64
```

segs is an array of the column names. I get the same result if I use `df.loc[:,segs]`

All rows seem to have this problem, but as a check of the first five shown, (7.40+7.49+7.48+7.48+7.32)/5 == 7.43.

I tried inserting a NaN or two into a test dataframe and that was not enough to reproduce the issue. What is going on here?

Comment: Are you saying that `df[segs].mean(1)` doesn't give you what's expected?

Comment: Do you have the right `dtypes`? What is the result of `df[segs].dtypes`?

Comment: I think you got it tmrivi. only Seg_11 is a float64, the rest are objects. The original file included a bunch of "m" characters in some of the columns that I replaced with NaN's, but have not converted the dtypes

Comment: print(segs) please....what does that return?